# An Unique key/id that corresponds to only one combination of Ubuntu OS and hardware

Tags: 18.04, kernel, security, system, keyrings

I need an unique ID/key such that it corresponds to only one combination of UbuntuOS and hardware. Maybe like a combination of machineID and something unique OS ID?

It should be such that the ID is generated only for this particular OS and hardware and that any other combination of OS and hardware generate different ID/key. In a nutshell, it should be an unique identifier for this particular combination of OS and hardware.

Answer (score 2):

To uniquely identify hardware is what machine-id is created for. Due pay extra attention to the last paragraph.

> **Synopsis**
>
> [/etc/machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html)
>
> **Description**
>
> The `/etc/machine-id` file contains the unique machine ID of the local system that is set during installation or boot. The machine ID is a single newline-terminated, hexadecimal, 32-character, lowercase ID. When decoded from hexadecimal, this corresponds to a 16-byte/128-bit value. This ID may not be all zeros.
>
> The machine ID is usually generated from a random source during system installation or first boot and stays constant for all subsequent boots. Optionally, for stateless systems, it is generated during runtime during early boot if necessary.
>
> This ID uniquely identifies the host. It should be considered "confidential", and must not be exposed in untrusted environments, in particular on the network((. If a stable unique identifier that is tied to the machine is needed for some application, the machine ID or any part of it must not be used directly. Instead the machine ID should be hashed with a cryptographic, keyed hash function, using a fixed, application-specific key. That way the ID will be properly unique, and derived in a constant way from the machine ID but there will be no way to retrieve the original machine ID from the application-specific one. The sd_id128_get_machine_app_specific(3) API provides an implementation of such an algorithm.

The last paragraph explains how to use this in applications: you need to hash machine-id before exposing it to an application or when using to connect to something. That means you need to code something: you need to create a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) and hash machine-id. That salt could be an identifier that is your OS.

Comment: That doesnt include OS right? So anybody with another copy of the OS on the same machine will get the same id right?

Comment: Yeah. Pay attention to the last part: you already should not be using it in software and need to hash it. Your OS could be part of the "salt" that you use for the hashing. Nobody ever made a unique id with the OS as part of it. The OS is not kept long enough to be a viable component of something that should be fixed for the duration of the machine having an OS.

Comment: It says that the machine-id is generated "from a random source during installation or first boot", by the OS I assume. Does that not mean that when re-installing the OS on the same machine, the machine-id will also change?

Comment: yes there is even a command to change it: `dbus-uuidgen --ensure=/etc/machine-id` though it is not advised to do this on a running machine. `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` should also (and always) have the same id as /etc/machine-id.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind for the detailed answer. Regarding the salt that could be an identifier for OS, what is unique about the OS that can be an identifier? I need an unique identifier for every unique combination of an OS and hardware.